# Getting lost configuring IdentityServer4 for SPA

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4, single-page-application, identity

I have been through MS docs and IdentityServer docs. I am still stuck.
I have tried every config option and I've reached breaking point.

I started with the MS SPA template, added AspNet Core Identity, and fiddled with these setting. I'm able to call the Api's using Postman, and get a token, it has authority, and scope, and name set, but the API's show null in User.Identity when I debug.

Currently my error is this:

**WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"**

Here is my configureServices:

```
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add ASP.Net Core Identity
            // this handles user authentication as well as user registration and management
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AccountingDbContext>();

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            // Handle authentication and authorization using Open ID Connect.
            // The components for authentication and authorization are:
            //   - user
            //   - client (the Angular app)
            //   - identity provider (ASP.Net Core Identity with IdentityServer4), and
            //   - resource server (the api)
            // identity provider and resource server are hosted together.
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<User, AccountingDbContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.ApiResources
                        .First() // represents the configured default Api
                        .UserClaims
                        .Add(JwtClaimTypes.Name);
                })
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

            // Add Controllers with API
            services.AddControllers();
            .AddMvcOptions(options =>
            {
                // Adding an empty Authorise filter means that any Authenticated user is valid.
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter());
            });


            // For Azure App Service deployments on Linux
            if (!Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(
                IdentityServerJwtConstants.IdentityServerJwtBearerScheme,
                options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Authority");
                });
            }

            // Authenticate requests to the Api
            // accepts any access token issued by identity server
            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Authority");
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateAudience = false
                    };
                })
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();

            // https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html
            // Adds Authorization policy to make sure the token has scope 'Accounting.ApplicationAPI openid profile'
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                // Registers the Policy with Authorization middleware
                options.AddPolicy("Accounting.ApplicationAPI", policy =>
                {
                    // Policy specifies that any Authenticated user with Accounting.ApplicationAPI scope is valid.
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policy.RequireClaim("scope", "Accounting.ApplicationAPI openid profile");
                });
            });


            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "./Accounting.Ng/dist";
            });
        }
```

and configure:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers()
                    .RequireAuthorization("Accounting.ApplicationAPI");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "../Accounting.Ng";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer(Configuration["AngularServer"]);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: My general advice is not to put all services in the same instance , instead I recommend you put IdentityServer, the client and the API on different services, then its much easier to  reason about and troubleshoot.

Comment: That error suggests that the API has a different idea of whats the public key(s) are than the thing issueing them. This may be related to a timing issue during bootstrapping - i.e. the API trying to load metadata that doesn't exist yet from the discovery endpoint. As Tore says... split them out.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).